# Как сделать подобную галерею на bootstrap3, чтобы высота рамки была фиксированная, а внутри неё изображения и подписи?

Tags: html, css

[image: галерея]

Как сделать подобную галерею на bootstrap3, чтобы высота рамки была фиксированная, а внутри неё изображения и подписи?

Comment: Сделайте рамки фиксированными, а внутрь поместите изображения и подписи.:)

Comment: также, как и на обычном CSS. ничего сверхъестественного здесь)

Answer (score 1):

Тривиальным решение - задать конкретную высоту у обвертки для картинки, но дабы сделать это responsive (адаптивным) - следует задавать не высоту а пропорции.

Оберните картинку в `<div>`, у которого вы зададите пропорции, а самой картинке задайте абсолютное позиционирование:

```
.item-img-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 70%; /* процент пропорции */
}

.item-img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Для того чтобы рассчитать **процент пропорции** используйте формулу

```
ratio = width / height
paddingTop = ration * 100
```

Предположим пропорция контейнера будут 3 к 4. Тогда

```
paddingTop = 3 / 4 * 100 = 75%
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/LxKpxY